# Strapi, :collection-type/:id with locale

Tags: javascript, strapi

I'm currently trying to get localized data for one specific instance of a Collection Type.

Let's say I have a Collection Type called Project.

If I want to get all Projects in french I just need to call the exposed endpoint `myApi/projects` with the parameter `_locale=fr` `myApi/projects?_locale=fr` and it's working pretty well.

But if I try to get one specific project for example `myApi/projects/1?_locale=fr` it returns a `404 not found`.

By the way, `myApi/projects/1` return the project but in the default locale which is english.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Localized entries on collection types are considered as a separate entry, rather than a "localized version of the entry". i.e. `myApi/projects/1`'s french version will have a different id, such as `myApi/projects/7`.

To see which id corresponds with which language, call `myApi/projects?locale=<lang>`.

Answer (score 0):

You still can get localizations for particular ID by doing `GET /api/restaurants/1?populate=localizations`. For more details: [Getting localized entries with the
locale
parameter](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/i18n#getting-localized-entries-with-the-locale-parameter)